# Data-bind visible knockout.js with OR

Tags: knockout.js

I am doing an OR check for the visibility of a control but it is not working as expected.
Below is the code for the same.

```
<span data-bind="visible: (test1()==='a' || test() === 'a')>a</span>

var viewModel = {
test : ko.observable('a'),
test1 : ko.observable('a')
};

 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Even if test1 and test had real names it would be unclear when its visible. Tip move the check to a computed observable on the VM with a good explaining name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not closed the quotes in your data-bind attribute value.

```
<span data-bind="visible: (test1()==='a' || test() === 'a')**"**>a</span>
```

The closing **"** was missing

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GbvfH/)

Comment: Thanks it works...my bad...bad way to start my day :(

Comment: No problem.. It happens :)